# 2-3 Tree in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, tree

I could not find a textbook implementation of a 2-3 tree in python, so I decided I will try to do mine.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        self.nodeType = 2
        self.d1, self.d2, self.d3 = data, None, None
        self.c1, self.c2, self.c3, self.c4 = None, None, None, None
        self.parent = parent
    def push(self, data):
        if self.nodeType == 2:
            self.nodeType = 3
            self.d1, self.d2 = sorted([self.d1, data])
        elif self.nodeType == 3:
            self.nodeType = 4
            self.d1, self.d2, self.d3 = sorted([self.d1, self.d2, data])
    def split(self):
        # Case O, if there is nothing to do
        if self.nodeType < 4:
            return
        # Case I, splitting when there is no parent
        if self.parent == None:
            leftChild = Node(self.d1, self)
            rightChild = Node(self.d3, self)
            leftChild.c1, leftChild.c2 = self.c1, self.c2
            rightChild.c1, rightChild.c2 = self.c3, self.c4
            self.nodeType = 2
            self.d1, self.d2, self.d3 = self.d2, None, None
            self.c1, self.c2, self.c3, self.c4 = leftChild, rightChild, None, None
        # Case II, when parent is a 2-node
        elif self.parent.nodeType == 2:
            # subcase a: when the current node is the left child of the parent node
            if self == self.parent.c1:
                midChild = Node(self.d3, self.parent)
                midChild.c1, midChild.c2 = self.c3, self.c4
                self.parent.push(self.d2)
                self.parent.c1, self.parent.c2, self.parent.c3 = self.parent.c1, midChild, self.parent.c2
                self.nodeType = 2
                self.c1, self.c2, self.c3, self.c4 = self.c1, self.c2, None, None
                self.d1, self.d2, self.d3 = self.d1, None, None
            # subcase b: when the current node is the right child of the parent node
            elif self == self.parent.c2:
                midChild = Node(self.d1, self.parent)
                midChild.c1, midChild.c2 = self.c1, self.c2
                self.parent.push(self.d2)
                self.parent.c1, self.parent.c2, self.parent.c3 = self.parent.c1, midChild, self.parent.c2
                self.nodeType = 2
                self.c1, self.c2, self.c3, self.c4 = self.c3, self.c4, None, None
                self.d1, self.d2, self.d3 = self.d3, None, None
        # Case III, when parent is a 3-node
        elif self.parent.nodeType == 3:
            # subcase a: when the current node is the left child of the parent node
            if self == self.parent.c1:
                newNode = Node(self.d3, self.parent)
                newNode.c1, newNode.c2 = self.c3, self.c4
                self.parent.push(self.d2)
                self.parent.c1, self.parent.c2, self.parent.c3, self.parent.c4 = self.parent.c1, newNode, self.parent.c2, self.parent.c3
                self.nodeType = 2
                self.c1, self.c2, self.c3, self.c4 = self.c1, self.c2, None, None
                self.d1, self.d2, self.d3 = self.d1, None, None
            # subcase b: when the current node is the middle child of the parent node
            elif self == self.parent.c2:
                newNode = Node(self.d3, self.parent)
                newNode.c1, newNode.c2 = self.c3, self.c4
                self.parent.push(self.d2)
                self.parent.c1, self.parent.c2, self.parent.c3, self.parent.c4 = self.parent.c1, self.parent.c2, newNode, self.parent.c3
                self.nodeType = 2
                self.c1, self.c2, self.c3, self.c4 = self.c1, self.c2, None, None
                self.d1, self.d2, self.d3 = self.d1, None, None
            # subcase c: when the current node is the right node of the parent node
            elif self == self.parent.c3:
                newNode = Node(self.d1, self.parent)
                newNode.c1, newNode.c2 = self.c1, self.c2
                self.parent.push(self.d2)
                self.parent.c1, self.parent.c2, self.parent.c3, self.parent.c4 = self.parent.c1, self.parent.c2, newNode, self.parent.c3
                self.nodeType = 2
                self.c1, self.c2, self.c3, self.c4 = self.c3, self.c4, None, None
                self.d1, self.d2, self.d3 = self.d3, None, None
            # now recursively split the parent
            self.parent.split()
    def insert(self, data):
        # if this node is a leaf
        if self.c1 == None:
            self.push(data)
            self.split()
        # if this node is not a leaf, and a 2-node
        elif self.nodeType == 2:
            if data < self.d1:
                self.c1.insert(data)
            else:
                self.c2.insert(data)
        # if this node is a 3-node
        elif self.nodeType == 3:
            if data < self.d1:
                self.c1.insert(data)
            elif data > self.d3:
                self.c3.insert(data)
            else:
                self.c2.insert(data)
    def find(self, data):
        # if this node is a leaf
        if self.c1 == None:
            if data in [self.d1, self.d2, self.d3]:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        # if this node is not a leaf, and a 2-node
        elif self.nodeType == 2:
            if data < self.d1:
                self.c1.find(data)
            else:
                self.c2.find(data)
        # if this node is a 3-node
        elif self.nodeType == 3:
            if data < self.d1:
                self.c1.find(data)
            elif data > self.d3:
                self.c3.find(data)
            else:
                self.c2.find(data)

class TwoThreeTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.isEmpty = True
        self.root = None
    def insert(self, data):
        if self.isEmpty:
            self.isEmpty = False
            self.root = Node(data)
        else:
            self.root.insert(data)
    def find(self, data):
        if self.isEmpty:
            return False
        else:
            self.root.find(data)
```

General feedback on the coding style is welcome. I am also looking for some specific feedback:

- This seems to be a lot of casework. How can I reuse more of my code to make it more elegant? I also believe that being able to organize this code more nicely means that I'd be able to generalize this for a more general B-Tree. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

My impressions on reading the question:

- I bet there's a WikiPedia article on 2-3 trees. But OP gave no link. :(
- No doc block describing 2-3 trees
- No invariant
- Lots of, as you say, "case work" encoded in if/elif statements that should probably be subclasses.

Digging in:

**Check the Docs**

You have more fields than are needed. 2-3 tree nodes have either 2 children and 1 data field, or 3 children an 2 data fields. You have `self.d3` and `self.c4` in your initializer...

**Own the node**

You have a tree class and a node class. Move the node class(es) into the tree:

```
class TwoThreeTree:
    '''Implement a 2-3 tree using pure Python 3. 

    See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-3_tree

    '''
    class _2node:
        def __init__(self, data=None, left=None, right=None):
            self.data = data
            self.left = left
            self.right = right

        def insert(self, data):
            ...

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.root is None

    def insert(self, data):
        if self.is_empty():
            self.root = self._2node(data)
        else:
            self.root = self.root.insert(data)
```

**Simplify and Subclass**

Once you've got the nodes inside the tree class, split them off. Python does duck-typing, so they don't need to share a common ancestor (although they might, if you find enough behavior to inherit).

```
class _2node:
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        ...
    def insert(self, ...): 
        ...

class _3node:
    def __init__(self, data1, data2=None, left=None, right=None):
        ...
    def insert(self, ...): 
        ...
```

You may wish to add a `.parent` link pointing up the tree, to simplify the split code.

**Add an Invariant**

Write yourself a method (or methods) called `invariant()`. Assert whatever things you find to assert - I think the wikipedia article has some pretty solid candidates. Call it when you're about to exit a public method, and whereever else you feel the need.

Comment: I do not understand why having `_2node` and `_3node` as seperate classes would help.

Comment: Everywhere you have "if nodeType == 2" or "if nodeType==3" is a different behavior. If those were different classes, you just write the code and *know* what the nodeType is.